# Not able to run protractor tests in Safari

Tags: angular, safari, protractor

I have Angular7 project and few E2E tests, in Chrome everything fine (All tests 'OK'). But i need to run my tests in Safari, and Protractor crashes with error.

First i had protractor.conf.js with :

```
multiCapabilities: [{ 'browserName': 'safari' }],
directConnect: true,
```

But i get:
`Error: browserName safari is not supported with directConnect.`

Then i change it to: 
`directConnect: false`.

But now protractor crashes with error:

```
E/launcher - Error: Error: Server terminated early with status 1
    at earlyTermination.catch.e (...node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js:252:52)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[10:52:05] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
An unexpected error occurred: undefined
```

Comment: If you look at [driverProviders/direct.ts](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/driverProviders/direct.ts), it does not support Safari. Direct connect supports Firefox and Chrome browsers and connects to them with the binaries downloaded.

Comment: Thanks. Chrome & FF work fine. But how to run tests in Safari? I have read that no webdriver needed for  >Safari10...

Answer (score 0):

There was no answer for this issue in any forum, but I finally found a solution. the error happens because of Direct connect. It doesn't support Safari. The solution is to give the seleniumServerJar path

seleniumServerJar:'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar',

it looks like below in the config file:

[image: Click the image below]